# Как кликнуть на radio элемент с заданным текстом

Tags: javascript

На странице есть `radio` элемент, на который я хочу кликнуть. Таких элементов много, поэтому я хочу найти нужный и кликнуть на него.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(t, function(el) {
    // Do stuff here
    if (el.innerText == "Нужный элемент") {
        el.click()
    }
});
```

Почему-то данный клик не отрабатывается. Также пробовал `check()` - результат аналогичен.

```
<div class="radio">
    <label title="">
        <input type="radio" name="title" value="Н235"><!-- react-text: 149 -->Нужный элементы<!-- /react-text -->
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У `input`-а вообще нет текста внутри: `<!-- react-text: 149 -->Нужный элементы<!-- /react-text -->` находится внутри `label`
2. Так как в `innerText` могут оказаться, например, пробельные символы в начале и в конце (а в вопросе вообще "Нужный элемент**ы**"), то либо нужно всё лишнее обрезать, либо вместо проверки на равенство строк использовать поиск подстроки в строке

В итоге получается так:

```js
var t = document.querySelectorAll("label");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(t, function(el) {
  if (el.innerText.indexOf("Нужный элемент") != -1) {
    el.querySelector("input").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="radio">
   <label title="">
      <input type="radio" name="title" value="Н234"/>
      Совсем не тот элемент
   </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
   <label title="">
      <input type="radio" name="title" value="Н235"/>
      Нужный элемент
   </label>
</div>
```

---

Если нужно не именно кликнуть на элемент, а просто выбрать нужный, то вместо `click()` имеет смысл устанавливать свойство `checked`:

```
el.querySelector("input").checked  = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 способа решения вашей задачи:

**Первый:**

```js
var elms  = document.querySelectorAll('label');

[].forEach.call(elms, function(el)
{
 if(el.innerHTML.indexOf('Нужный элемент 149') >= 0)
  el.click()
});
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="title" value="Н235"><!-- react-text: 149 -->Нужный элемент 149<!-- /react-text --></label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="title" value="Н236"><!-- react-text: 150 -->Нужный элемент 150<!-- /react-text --></label>
```

**Второй:**

```js
var elms  = document.querySelectorAll('input');

[].forEach.call(elms, function(el)
{
    if(el.value == 'Н236')
  el.click()
});
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="title" value="Н235"><!-- react-text: 149 -->Нужный элемент 149<!-- /react-text --></label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="title" value="Н236"><!-- react-text: 150 -->Нужный элемент 150<!-- /react-text --></label>
```